# How to find out below output using oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Input:

```
col1  col2
------------
1 A
2 1
3 B
4 2
5 C
6 Null
```

Output i want

```
Col1 Col2
__________
A  1
B  2
C Null
```

Comment: Please explain the logic.  It is not obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I see.  Assuming there are no gaps in `col1`, you can use aggregation using arithmetic:

```
select max(case when mod(id, 2) = 0 then col2 end),
       max(case when mod(id, 2) = 1 then col2 end)
from t
group by floor((id - 1) / 2);
```

Another method uses `lead()`:

```
select col2, next_col2
from (select t.*, lead(col2) over (order by id) as next_col2
      from t
     ) t
where mod(id, 2) = 1;
```

Comment: Generally, in languages (like PL/SQL) where indexing starts from 1 rather than 0, and that support the `ceil` function, grouping can be expressed more simply like so: `group by ceil(id/2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use join to the *next* row of the same table and limit to every other row.

```
select t1.col2 col1, t2.col2
from tab t1
join tab t2 on t1.col1 = t2.col1 -1
where mod(t1.col1,2) = 1

C C
- -
A 1
B 2
C
```

Again, it assumes that your sequence in `col1`is without gaps.

Answer (score 0):

This is an application of `PIVOT`, available since Oracle 11.1. (A much shorter solution is possible in Oracle 12.1 and higher, using `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`, but the question is explicitly tagged `oracle11g`.)

I use the analytic function `ROW_NUMBER()` to prepare the data, so that we don't need to assume anything about the ordering column - it may have gaps, and/or it doesn't even have to be a `number` column, it can be date or string or anything else that can be ordered.

Setup:

```
create table sample_data (col1, col2) as
    select 1, 'A'  from dual union all
    select 2, '1'  from dual union all
    select 3, 'B'  from dual union all
    select 4, '2'  from dual union all
    select 5, 'C'  from dual union all
    select 6, null from dual
;
```

Query and output:

```
select col1, col2
from   (
         select ceil(row_number() over (order by col1) / 2) as r,
                mod (row_number() over (order by col1) , 2) as c, col2
         from   sample_data
       )
pivot  (min(col2) for c in (1 as col1, 0 as col2))
order  by r
;


COL1 COL2
---- ----
A    1   
B    2   
C
```

Just for fun, and for whoever may have this problem in Oracle 12 or higher, here is the `match_recognize` solution:

```
select col1, col2
from   sample_data
match_recognize(
  order    by col1
  measures x.col2 as col1, y.col2 as col2
  pattern  ( x y? )
  define   x as null is null
);
```